# Visual Studio 2013 EE GL/glu.h No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl

When I compile I have this error in file glew.h

```
error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'GL/glu.h': No such file or directory.
```

In my project I have added in Linker->Input:

```
SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib SDL2_mixer.lib SDL2_ttf.lib opengl32.lib glew32.lib
```

Comment: You got to include the `include` folder in the `additional include directories` section

Comment: I have in: VC++ Directory both: $(SolutionDir)deps/include/ and $(SolutionDir)deps/lib/ but don't work. I don't understand why it works at home and not in the office PC!